# Rename columns in an xlsx file without reading/writing the whole file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I have some relatively large Excel files of type .xlsx containing a single sheet in which one column needs to be renamed in every file.

| column_a | column_b | wrong_name | column_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

needs to be

| column_a | column_b | column_c | column_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I understand this can be done by reading the file into memory, replacing the column name, and then overwriting the original file e.g. with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')
df.rename(columns={'wrong_name', 'column_c'}, inplace=True)
df.to_excel('my_file.xlsx')
```

And I can read just the columns and replace the problematic column name so I have a list with the correct names:

```py
cols = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx', nrows=0).columns.to_list()
new_cols = [x if x != 'wrong_name' else 'column_c' for x in cols]
```

But I can't figure out a way to write just the list of column names back to the source .xlsx file as the top row without overwriting the rest of the data.

Is there any way in Python to modify just the column names in the .xlsx file without having to read and write the whole file each time?

Comment: How do you qualify a column name in a specific file as *wrong* ? Do all the files have always the same valid column names and a single wrong one (*that has a random name*) ?

Comment: The 'wrong' name and the replacement name are both known values and are the same for all files.

Comment: Use openpyxl, if necessary combine read-only and write-only modes.